# How to check if a given Java Regex is valid in Python

Tags: java, python, regex

I want to check if the Regex defined in Java is valid by Python.

But the Regex in the two languages are little different.

For example, to parse the character dot (`.`)

```
"\."  # Python version
"\\." # Java version
```

Is there any way to check Java regex in Python?

Comment: did you want to check for this particular regex?

Comment: regex to match literal dot in both languages `[.]`

Comment: OP is not looking to just parse the dot it seems.

Comment: Go to regex101.com.Select python and put your regex there.That's d best way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex are the same in java and python. The difference you pointed out is due to the way java compiler handles string constants. 
Backslash has special meaning as an escape character, so, to include a backslash itself into a String literal, you have to repeat it twice. Thus `"\\."` to express a string constant `"\."`

Try this: `System.out.println(Pattern.compile("\\.").toString());`

Comment: i think you need to escape the backslash one more time in python like java when the regex is not defined as raw string.